# Using Chirpy in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, chirpy

I'm trying to set Chirpy up - we are moving from MS Visual Studio 2010 to 2012.  I know that it should end up in the Addins folder, but I do not see it listed under tools -> addins.  Any thoughts?

We're using an older version (for Github, no one wants to upgrade so that we don't have Git issues) - so it may not be as simple as this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to edit the file C:\Users{USER}\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Addins\Zippy.Addin

Change the 10.0 to 11.0, after that it should work fine.

Comment: Edit the file, change the version, and then when you open up the Add In manager in VS2012 it will show up and you can enable it.

Comment: `Documents` should be `My Documents`.  Can't edit less than 6 characters apparently.

Comment: It's worth noting that there are two places where you need to edit. Editing just the first didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are two places where you should edit:

```
    <HostApplication>
        <Name>Microsoft Visual Studio Macros</Name>
        <Version>XX.0</Version>
    </HostApplication>
    <HostApplication>
        <Name>Microsoft Visual Studio</Name>
        <Version>XX.0</Version>
    </HostApplication>
```

Change the XX.0:

If you have VS2012 then put in: 11.0
If you have VS2013 then put in: 12.0

Restart VS en the add-in will be there ;)